# Servlet load properties file

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I customize Servlet with the block code as below:

```
public class StartupServlet2 extends HttpServlet {
   public static Properties common;

    public void init( ServletConfig config ) throws ServletException {

        super.init(config);

        //
        String tempClassName = (String)System.getProperty("testProp");
}
}
```

properties file test.properties (WEB-INF/test.properties):

```
testProp=test value
```

**Issue:** when server is starting, it cannot load properties file so that it cannot get testProp value.
**Question:**
I use tomcat server that cannot load test.properties file. How can I load the properties file during starting time ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ServletContextListener
```

You can implement ServletContextListener to initialize or clean up something.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html